# How to detect if a role was mention Discord py

Tags: python, discord

So I'm creating a bot that can change the perms of roles. and to start I wanted to code a thing that allows me see and check what role has been mentioned. I want the identification to be open to all roles not just one because later on I want to be able to change the perms of multiple roles at once.

```
    @client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message == client.user:
  return

 if message.channel.name in ['general']:
   if message.content.lower().startswith('!rc'):
     role = str(message.role.id)
     await message.channel.send (f'{message.role.mention}')
     return
```

So far I have tried doing this where I create a .startswith for the initial command then I create a "role" variable that I then use to mention that role but this doesn't work, can someone help/point me in the right direction in getting this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `on_message` event for these type of commands because you would need to put a bunch of code to solve this problem with that event. Use the below code which helps to solve your problem in an easy manner

```py
@client.command()
async def role(ctx,role:discord.Role):
  if ctx.channel.name=="general":
    await ctx.send(role.mention)
```